# How to hide the Cart Subtotal amount in mini cart popup in magento 2

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, magento-2.0, mini-cart, magento2.3.2

Please suggest the solution to hide the Cart Subtotal amount and product price in the mini cart popup.

Only i need to show the number of quantity items in the popup.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this, you would need to edit 2 files.

Magento_Checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/subtotal.html, it should contain this:

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<div class="subtotal">

    <!-- ko foreach: elems -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

and this file Magento_Checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/default.html

it should contain this:

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<li class="item product product-item" data-role="product-item">
    <div class="product">
        <!-- ko if: product_has_url -->
        <a data-bind="attr: {href: product_url, title: product_name}" tabindex="-1" class="product-item-photo">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('itemImage') -->
                <!-- ko template: {name: getTemplate(), data: item.product_image} --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        </a>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko ifnot: product_has_url -->
        <span class="product-item-photo">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('itemImage') -->
                <!-- ko template: {name: getTemplate(), data: item.product_image} --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        </span>
        <!-- /ko -->

        <div class="product-item-details">
            <strong class="product-item-name">
                <!-- ko if: product_has_url -->
                <a data-bind="attr: {href: product_url}, html: product_name"></a>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko ifnot: product_has_url -->
                    <!-- ko text: product_name --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
            </strong>

            <!-- ko if: options.length -->
            <div class="product options" data-mage-init='{"collapsible":{"openedState": "active", "saveState": false}}'>
                <span data-role="title" class="toggle"><!-- ko i18n: 'See Details' --><!-- /ko --></span>

                <div data-role="content" class="content">
                    <strong class="subtitle"><!-- ko i18n: 'Options Details' --><!-- /ko --></strong>
                    <dl class="product options list">
                        <!-- ko foreach: { data: options, as: 'option' } -->
                        <dt class="label"><!-- ko text: option.label --><!-- /ko --></dt>
                        <dd class="values">
                            <!-- ko if: Array.isArray(option.value) -->
                                <span data-bind="html: option.value.join('<br>')"></span>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                            <!-- ko ifnot: Array.isArray(option.value) -->
                                <span data-bind="text: option.value"></span>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                        </dd>
                        <!-- /ko -->
                    </dl>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /ko -->

            <div class="product-item-pricing">

                <div class="details-qty qty">
                    <label class="label" data-bind="i18n: 'Qty', attr: {
                           for: 'cart-item-'+item_id+'-qty'}"></label>
                    <input data-bind="attr: {
                           id: 'cart-item-'+item_id+'-qty',
                           'data-cart-item': item_id,
                           'data-item-qty': qty,
                           'data-cart-item-id': product_sku
                           }, value: qty"
                           type="number"
                           size="4"
                           class="item-qty cart-item-qty">
                    <button data-bind="attr: {
                           id: 'update-cart-item-'+item_id,
                           'data-cart-item': item_id,
                           title: $t('Update')
                           }"
                            class="update-cart-item"
                            style="display: none">
                        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Update'"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="product actions">
                <!-- ko if: is_visible_in_site_visibility -->
                <div class="primary">
                    <a data-bind="attr: {href: configure_url, title: $t('Edit item')}" class="action edit">
                        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Edit'"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <div class="secondary">
                    <a href="#" data-bind="attr: {'data-cart-item': item_id, title: $t('Remove item')}"
                       class="action delete">
                        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Remove'"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

This will solve your issue, change it in your theme, or can override the html files in your custom module

Comment: Hello, I'm new to magento.I don't know how to override the core file. can you please help me to override the core file. please share the exact folder structure to override the files.

Comment: so, are you familiar with module creation/theme creation?

Comment: I Am not familiar with both the options. This month only i started to doing POC and as well as learning magento.

Comment: Oh, then it would be a little difficult to explain man. sorry

Comment: Hi, i have added the both the files which you are shared under the app/design/frontend/custom/luma-en/Magento_Checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/subtotal.html and  app/design/frontend/custom/luma-en/Magento_Checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/default.html. after run the cli commands nothing will reflected.correct me if i'm wrong?

Comment: check in admin or themes table in database, whether your theme is recognized or not. if it's not, if it's not, you can download this theme of mine https://github.com/manishjoy/frontend-slate-theme

it inherits blank theme, if you want, you can edit theme.xml file

Comment: Already we extend Magento Luma theme to Luma english. so currently we are using luma english theme. my parent theme is Magento Luma.

Comment: Theme path: app/design/frontend/custom/luma-en. Vendor name is custom and theme name is luma-en.

Comment: hi, thanks its working. but the Cart Subtotal amount is still showing. but the label is removed. any suggestion?

Comment: can you provide the url, I could check.

Comment: also, if it works, please upvote my answer

Comment: this is local website. still not released to the production environment

Comment: okay, at least upload the screenshot somewhere and show

Comment: i have edited this question and added one more screenshot please check.

Comment: Okay, empty the entire subtotal.html and then try. Also, if it works, please upvote my answers

Comment: ok sure i will edit the file and upvote your answer. thank you.

Comment: Thank you so much :)

Comment: upvoted done. if you know the answer for this question. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/297283/how-to-remove-the-cart-shipping-and-payment-page-product-price-and-subtotal-amo . pls answer.

Comment: You will need to customize several files for this question. so, I would recomment to get familiar with magento theme customization using http://excellencemagentoblog.com/